# Trouble trying to overriding !important style

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to make the fields for filling out an ecommerce checkout address appear after the user starts typing the zip code.

For that, I wrote this JS code below

```
<script>


window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('billing_postcode').onclick = function(){
    //console.log('Hello world');
   
document.getElementById('billing_address_1_field').element.style.setProperty("display", "block", "important");

document.getElementById('billing_address_2_field').element.style.setProperty("display", "block", "important");

document.getElementById('billing_billing_number_field').element.style.setProperty("display", "block", "important");

document.getElementById('billing_city_field').element.style.setProperty("display", "block", "important");

document.getElementById('billing_state_field').element.style.setProperty("display", "block", "important");
  }
}



</script>
```

And this is the CSS I need to overwrite

```
#billing_address_1_field {
    display: none !important;
}

#billing_address_2_field{
    display: none !important;
}

#billing_billing_number_field{
    display: none !important;
}

#billing_city_field{
    display: none !important;
}

#billing_state_field{
    display: none !important;
}
```

I'm getting this error on the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.document.getElementById.onclick ((index):384)
document.getElementById.onclick @ (index):384
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: it should be `document.getElementById('billing_address_1_field').style`. `.element` should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try removing the 'element' from each of the 'setProperty' statements.
i.e:  `document.getElementById('billing_state_field').style.setProperty("display", "block", "important");`